# What is $\max $ and $ \min $ in set theory?

Tags: functions

I keep seeing $\max ( \cdot ) $ and $ \min ( \cdot ) $ everywhere.

> EDIT :
>
> It appears like this, $\max(4,9]$ or $\min[a,b)$ or sometimes with
>   curly brackets, $\max \{0,100 \}$ etc.
>
> I can sort of guess what it means, but I don't know what they are...

First of all, what is it even called? Is it a property of set, or a function?

Is it the same as supremum and infimum thing from Real Analysis?

PS : Idk the correct tag for this..

Thank you :)

Comment: you will want to give a more thorough example for context. min and max can apply to any kind of ordering. There are certainly orderings in set theory but to determine what you're seeing we would need more information.

Comment: They are called minimum and maximum. For us to be any more specific, you're going to have to provide a lot more context.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Alright done! I can't provide more context because I don't know what they are, they appear frequently though just like in the examples I gave.

Comment: @William The examples you just gave are what provided the necessary context to answer the question. Math's a big world, and believe it or not, those couple of examples really narrowed down what kind of things you're talking about.

Comment: If $(S,\leq)$ denotes a partial order then $\max$ can be looked at as a function $\mathcal S\to S$ where $\mathcal S:=\{A\in\wp(S)\mid A\text{ has a maximum}\}\subseteq\wp(S)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum of a totally ordered set is defined as an element that is greater than all the other elements. For example $\max(4,9] = 9$ since $9$ is in $(4,9]$ and is greater than all the other elements. On the other hand, $\max(4,9)$ does not exist. You can keep picking bigger and bigger elements, closer and closer to $9,$ but none of these is the maximum, since you can always find something a little closer.

Minimum is the same idea, of course. Just replace 'greater' with 'less than'.

Comment: Thank you good sir, but how do you read those things? And what are they? Properties of sets?

Comment: When I say "the maximum of a totally ordered set," it means the maximum is an operation on a totally ordered set, taking such a set and producing an element of that set. As I noted, this operation is not always defined (i.e. not every totally ordered set has a maximum). "Having a maximum" would be a property a totally ordered set could have or not have.

Answer (score 10):

If $S$ denotes a set and is equipped with a partial order $\leq$, and $A\subseteq S$ then $\max(A)$ exists if $A$ has an element $a$ such that $b\leq a$ is true for every $b\in A$.

In that case $a$ is unique and $\max(A):=a$.

In many cases such an element does not exist while a supremum does exist.

For instance $A=(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb R$ has $1$ as supremum, but it has no maximum. This because $1\notin A$.

Similar story for $\min(A)$.